# How to revert single iCloud calendar event edits/deletions?

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical

I have accidentally deleted an event from a shared iCloud calendar. Is there a way to restore it?

I don't want to restore the whole calendar from an earlier backup. Some new events have been added after the deletion, which I want to keep.

More generally, is there a way to access a history of changes made to the iCloud calendar, i.e. a list of all additions, deletions and edits?

The deleted event is still visible in the notifications popup:

[image]

Comment: If you performed no other steps afterwards it should be in the Undo buffer [or not many, idk how big the buffer is, possibly 5 events like Finder]

Comment: It's not in the Undo buffer anymore. Besides that, repeatedly undoing the last changes up to the deletion would also undo the additions that happened after the deletion, and I want to avoid that.

Comment: If it's a shared calendar, can you contact the owner and ask them to resend the event to you?  There's no list of changes that you can go back to and selectively restore.  If you don't want to do the Undo steps identified by @Tetsujin then this is the only way to get it back.